# C++ Reference Confusions (and some copy constructor ones as well)

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, pass-by-reference

so I have a question about passing by reference. I tried passing an object to a member function by reference and have that member function call another member function with the reference I passed as an argument. However, the compiler says that the member function invoked is not found. Why is that so? The code below will describe my frustration in ways my words cannot express themself

```
    // CODE 1
    class someClass {
        int data;
        public:
        someClass(someClass&);
        someClass someFunction(const someClass&)
    };

    someClass::someClass(someClass &obj) {
        data = obj.data;
    }


    someClass someClass::someFunction(const someClass &obj) {
        someClass demo(obj); // <- this doesn't work
        someClass demo(&obj); // <- neither does this
        someClass demo(*obj); // <- or this
        someClass demo2(*this); // <- this works though 
    }
```

Having a hard time understanding this, it may seem trivial but I do appreciate all the help I may get. Also, something mysterious has happened in xcode, when I tried the following (referring to CODE 2), it works. Any idea why?

```
    // CODE 2
    class someClass {
        int data;
        public:
        someClass(someClass&);
        void setData(int x) { data = x; }
    };

    int main() {
        someClass first;
        setData(10);
        someClass second;
        second = first;
        //Mysteriously, it worked without overloading the '=' operator. Why?
        //Also, I mentioned XCode just in case someone might say it's compiler specific

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I think that you need to show at least the prototype for demo and demo2 before you will get much help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficulties appear to be as follows:

```
someClass demo(obj);
```

You are trying to pass a const reference to a function that requires a reference that is not const. The typical pattern is to have a copy constructor take a const reference parameter, which avoids this problem.

```
someClass demo(&obj);
```

In this case, the compiler is looking for a constructor that takes a pointer to a someClass, but cannot find it. `&obj` returns a pointer to `obj`, not a reference to `obj`.

```
someClass demo(*obj);
```

In this case, you are attempting to dereference `obj` as if it was a pointer, but it is a reference, not a pointer.

```
someClass demo2(*this);
```

This works because you are dereferencing the `this` pointer, which points at an instance of `someClass`.

Comment: so what you're saying is because I'm passing a const reference to an obj in someFunction, therefore a const refer. obj is being passed to the constructor, but the constructor does not take const ref. obj. and hence it does not work?

Comment: That's correct. You can pass a non-const reference to a function that takes a const reference but you can't pass a const reference to a function that takes a non-const reference because that function might try to modify the referenced variable in its body, which it cannot do if the actual reference (as opposed to the dummy parameter) is const.